# Select/Unselect all CheckBox in a "CheckListBox" in XAML only

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I searched this topic and found several discussions.
What I didn't like about those implementations is that they either implied special kind of the bound data (with IsSelected property) or lacked normal keyboard support.

CheckBox in a list is more a decorative thing rather than functionalyty extension thus it should be treated accordingly.

I started from this nice and helpful article: http://www.gbogea.com/2010/01/02/mvvm-multiselect-listbox

But I beleive hacking View in favor of the ViewModel is not quite good practice. It's ViewModel to be adapted to View and Model. Surely, IMHO.

So I changed a little and finished with this XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="checkboxList"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Sports}"
                 Margin="0,5"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              Content="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Here CheckBox selection is in sync with ListBoxItem.IsSelected and ListBox is unaware of the bound data peculiarities.

This is Ok.
But Is there any way to add Select|Deselect All for the ListBox by adding one more checkbox to the control template? Using only XAML.

Comment: Uh.. forgot the question =) Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that using for example `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="All">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                            <is:CallMethodAction MethodName="SelectAll"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                            <is:CallMethodAction MethodName="UnselectAll"
                                    TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CheckBox>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>  
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

This however does not solve a problem you did not mention or think of, namely that the state of that `CheckBox` will not change when the selection is changed without using it. You could instead bind the `IsChecked` state using a `MultiBinding` and value converter to get it into the right state, you then could also drop the events. It is also rather messy though.